# Python subprocess in a script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I wrote a script using while loop.

It checks one condition if a statement isn't true my script starts a subprocess. Unfortunately when a subprocess is crashing the whole script stops working

Is there any solution that my script in python will work after a subprocess has an Exception and exit?

```
subprocess.Popen("sudo /usr/bin/python /home/tomc/Desktop/Tomek/test6.py", shell=True)
```

I mean the subprocess (test6.py) stops working but the main process res.py is still checking condition and after starts again subprocess test6.py

Comment: `.poll()` or `.communicate()` methods to the rescue. Depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why are you using sudo or a subprocess at all?

Comment: because my script test6.py works like 2-3 days and then throws an Exception and stops working. The script res.py has no problem with Exceptions and works the whole time

Comment: @PrzykładowyMail `try: unstable_code() except YourException: plan_b()` ?

Comment: but I don't know which kind of Exception there is. After 2-3 days my script crashs